# Calling repaint in multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, repaint

Since a few days I've been playing a bit with a small game in java.

Does it hurt java swing when 2 threads call repaint() at the same time?

I ask this because i have a paint thread, which calls repaint at a certain interval. In addition i call repaint when the player executes an action. Both repaint calls will repaint the same custom JPanel.

In theory repaint can then be called by 2 threads at the same time.

Comment: can you paste your code as well?

Comment: @Vishal it is quite big, but an example would have indeed be better, but it were 2 threads, one did call repaint as response to a button press (edt) and the other is simply a normal java thread (x extends Thread)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually `repaint()` can be called in the same time in this case. But it is not a problem.

Actually methods like `repaint()`, `revalidate()` are safe to use within any thread. Those methods actually queue requests to EDT(Event Dispatch Thread) to call `paint()` and `validate()`. So if you call `repaint()` many times using different threads, it will queue the request to call `paint()` method..

Click [here](http://da2i.univ-lille1.fr/doc/tutorial-java/uiswing/painting/concepts.html) for more about EDT.

It is not safe to call `paint()` method, without using EDT. (Better if you don't call forever.) But calling `repaint()` at same time using different threads will not be a problem..

Comment: hotzst got me a bit worried cause i was calling repaint from a non edt thread and remembered that this might be wrong, cause most of the time ui related things should not be directly accessed from such a thread. But lucky you came along. It indeed seems that you can safely call repaint from a non edt thread (a simple java thread). Thanks for the helpful reply!

Comment: repaint is done with `RepaintManager` after you have called `repaint()` method from any thread. `RepaintManager` will do its job correctly and paint components and we don't need to worry about that..

Comment: Is RepaintManager manager smart enough to only paint once if multiple calls to `repaint()` have happened before painting?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. All GUI updates need to be done by the same UI thread. This is not only true for Swing application but also for other UI frameworks and in other languages.
What you might be able to do is prepare the update of the UI in a different thread and then delegate the last step to the UI-Thread, which updates the GUI.